# React onClick function with Parameter Returning Undefined

Tags: function, reactjs, onclick

When I run the onEditNoteClick function, I am returned an error that says

```
  Cannot read property 'onEditNoteClick' of undefined
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this issue. To make it simpler, I set the onEditNoteClick parameter to 1 but it still doesn't work.

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onEditNoteClick = this.onEditNoteClick.bind(this);
  }

  ......

  onEditNoteClick(id){
    console.log("came to this function");
  }

  renderNotes(note) {
    return (
      <tr key={note.id}>
          <td> {note.name}</td>
          <td> {note.description} </td>
          <td className="edit" onClick={this.onEditNoteClick.bind(this,1)}><i className="fa fa-fw fa-pencil fa-lg"></i> </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

.....

render(){
   {this.props.notes.map(this.renderNotes)}
```

I think I need to add a bind method with the notes map, something like this:

```
   {this.props.notes.map(this.renderNotes).bind(this)}
```

But I'm not sure what the correct syntax is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I need to add a bind method with the notes map, something like this:
>
> ```
> {this.props.notes.map(this.renderNotes).bind(this)}
> ```

That would be incorrect. `.bind` can only be called on a *function*, but `.map` returns an *array*, not a function. What you have to is set the `this` value of the `this.renderNotes` method. The easiest way to achieve this would be to pass `this` as second argument to `.map` (see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

```
{this.props.notes.map(this.renderNotes, this)}
```

Alternatively, bind `this.renderNotes` in the `constructor` just like you do with the other method:

```
this.renderNotes = this.renderNotes.bind(this);
```

and then you can omit the second argument:

```
{this.props.notes.map(this.renderNotes)}
```

---

See also: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Thank you!